# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in my MEAN stack app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

In my app I when I'm receiving posts from my **NodeJS** backend, in the **Angular** front end I'm trying to transform it using `pipe()` operator and using the `map()` function.

Here is my `angular` code that sends the `http` request to the backend,

```
getPosts(userId: string, currentPage: number) {
    console.log(userId);
    this.http.get<{message: string, posts: any, maxPosts: number }> 
  ('http://localhost:3000/api/post/' + userId)
    .pipe(map((postData) => {
      console.log(postData);
      return { posts: postData.posts.map((post) => {
        return {
          title: post.title,
          content: post.content,
          id: post._id,
          imagePath: post.imagePath,
          creator: post.creator
        };
      }),
      maxPosts: postData.maxPosts};
    }))
    .subscribe(transformedPostsData => {
      this.posts = transformedPostsData.posts;
      this.postUpdate.next({
        post: [...this.posts],
        postCount: transformedPostsData.maxPosts
      });
    });
  }
```

The backend function that receives this request is given below,

```
 exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
  let fetchedPost;
  let maxPosts = 10;
  Post.find({ creator: req.params.userId }).then(post => {
    if(post) {
      res.status(200).json({
        fetchedPost: post,
        message: "Post successful",
        max: maxPosts
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Failed to get User Post"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

My first assumption was the request was not carrying the `userId` against which it should retrieve the posts, then printed it with `console.log(userId)`, it was fully fine.

Then I thought the backend was not returning any post or something `null`. Then I used `console.log(postData)`, which printed the post data perfectly.

Here is what it looks like,

[image]

The other questions on SO regarding this error did not really match with my situation. I went through them carefully.

Even the minimum clue would mean great help. Thank you.

Comment: did you import map ( `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` )?

Comment: Yes sir, imported it in the very first line.

Comment: Does `postData` has `posts`? I am guessing `postData.posts.map` this map is the issue.

Comment: The postData has posts. Sir, the thing is the exactly same code works fine in another of my service class. In this one I'm just trying to get the posts of a certain user, not all. But in the service class from which I retrieve all posts at once the `getPosts()` function is exactly the same.

Comment: user-profile.service.ts.26 is `console.log(postData)`?  On your console output I only see `fetchedPost` and not `posts`.

Comment: Sir, I'm returning that `fetchedPost` from backend to front end and receiving as `posts` in that `http.get<{message: string, posts: any, maxPosts: number}>`

Comment: @Emma is right, since you are logging `postData`, your log output shouldn't contain `fetchedPost` but `posts`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it solved !

Comment: @RatnadeepChakraborty you should post what fixed it below and the code that fixed it and mark it as the answer. You should also give credit to the comment.

Comment: Sir, I have voted their comments and it solved exactly what they advised to check, nothing different from their advice, that is why I did not post it again. Anyone reading the just comments will get the solution right away. Thanks for your concern.